# Validación de condicional JQuery

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

Chicos estoy teniendo problemas con este validador, no me toma los dos y me aplica estilos que no debe, por ejemplo me debería aplicar el fill a un path que no tiene el fill pero no lo hace y pone stroke a elementos que no lo debe poner según la lógica de la validación  y así con los diferentes elementos, no se que está fallando en la validación, aquí pongo el JS en un each ya que debe recorrer todos los SVG del sitio

```js
$("svg, svg g, svg g g, svg g g g").each(function() {
  $(this).children().each(function(index, child){
    caseElement = child.nodeName;
    
    colorFill = $(this).attr('fill');
    colorStroke = $(this).attr('stroke');
    switch (caseElement) {
      case 'path':
      if (colorFill !== undefined || colorFill !== 'none') {
        $(this).css('fill', 'red');
      }
      if (colorStroke !== undefined || colorStroke !== 'none') {
        $(this).css('stroke', 'red');
      }
      break;
      case 'circle':
      if (colorFill !== undefined || colorFill !== 'none') {
        $(this).css('fill', 'red');
      }
      if (colorStroke !== undefined || colorStroke !== 'none') {
        $(this).css('stroke', 'red');
      }
      break;
      case 'line':
      if (colorFill !== undefined || colorFill !== 'none') {
        $(this).css('fill', 'red');
      }
      if (colorStroke !== undefined || colorStroke !== 'none') {
        $(this).css('stroke', 'red');
      }
      break;
      case 'dojo':
      if (colorFill !== undefined || colorFill !== 'none') {
        $(this).css('fill', 'red');
      }
      if (colorStroke !== undefined || colorStroke !== 'none') {
        $(this).css('stroke', 'red');
      }
      break;
    }
  });
  
});
```

```css
svg {
  width: 100px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>



<svg id="Capa_1" version="1.1" baseProfile="tiny" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" x="0px" y="0px" viewBox="0 0 91.5 91.5" xml:space="preserve">
<path fill="#C4D600" d="M45.7,0C20.5,0,0,20.5,0,45.7s20.5,45.7,45.7,45.7C71,91.5,91.5,71,91.5,45.7C91.5,20.5,71.1,0,45.7,0                                  C45.8,0,45.8,0,45.7,0z M45.7,83.9c-21.1,0-38.1-17.1-38.1-38.1S24.7,7.6,45.7,7.6s38.1,17.1,38.1,38.1l0,0                                  C83.8,66.8,66.8,83.8,45.7,83.9z"></path>
<path d="M60.3,53.7c-8.1,8-21.1,8-29.2,0c-1.5-1.5-3.9-1.5-5.5,0c-1.5,1.5-1.5,3.9,0,5.5c11,11.1,28.8,11.2,39.9,0.2                                  c0.1-0.1,0.1-0.1,0.2-0.2c1.5-1.5,1.5-3.9,0-5.5C64.3,52.2,61.8,52.2,60.3,53.7L60.3,53.7z"></path>
<circle fill="none" cx="62.4" cy="32.6" r="4"></circle>
<circle fill="#C4D600" cx="29.4" cy="32.6" r="4"></circle>
</svg>
```

Muchas gracias por la ayuda

Answer (score 0):

Debes poner undefined de la siguiente manera:

```
 if (colorStroke !== “undefined”|| colorStroke !== 'none') {
        $(this).css('stroke', 'red');
      }
```

Comment: No amigo, no funciono así tampoco

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/858181/how-to-check-a-not-defined-variable-in-javascript quizás este enlace le sea de ayuda